# How can I set the time-zone for the Spark History Server?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

When I submit a job on a set of machines machine located in PST timezone, the Spark Master has the correct time, but the history server shows time that is 8 hrs ahead which is GMT.
Is there a way to fix this ?